# Why does "в субботу?" end in "-y"? Is it accusative?

Tags: грамматика, склонение

"Он работает в субботу" looks like the prepositional case, but it doesn't comply with the rules for the use of the prepositional. Is it accusative? If so, why is it accusative? There's no object in it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In Russian, when we answer the question "когда?", we use different prepositions and nouns. The choice of case depends on the noun.

1. If we use nouns such as момент, секунда, минута, час, день with "эта", "этот", the pattern is **в + винительный падеж**.

   > В эту минуту.

   > В этот день.
2. For days of the week (понедельник, вторник, среда, четверг, пятница, суббота, воскресенье), we use the same pattern
   **в + винительный падеж**. Mind that with вторник, we use the preposition **во**.

   > Мы уезжаем в понедельник.

   > Во вторник была хорошая погода.
3. For plural days of the week (e.g., "on Mondays") (понедельник, вторник, среда, четверг, пятница, суббота, воскресенье), we use the pattern **по + дательный падеж**.

   > Музей закрыт по понедельникам.
4. With "**неделя**" (эта, прошлая, следующая и т.д.), the pattern is **на + предложный падеж**.

   > На прошлой неделе приехали наши друзья.
5. With "**месяц**" (этот, прошлый, следующий и т.д.), the pattern is
   **в + предложный падеж.**

   > В следующем месяце будут выборы.

   > В июне он нашёл новую работу.
6. With "**год**" (этот, прошлый, следующий и т.д., а также с порядковым номером года), the pattern is **в + местный падеж**.

   > В этом году много солнечных дней.

   > В 2017-ом мы едем в Россию.
7. The word "**год**" can be used with the meaning "at that time" "это время", "в этот период времени", then **в + винительный падеж.**

   > В год моей жизни в Италии я выучил итальянский язык.

   > В годы войны многие уехали из страны.
8. With "**век**", the pattern is **в + предложный падеж.**

   > В XX-ом веке сделано много научных открытий.
9. If "**век**" is used with the meaning "это время", "в этот период времени", then use **в + винительный падеж.**

   > Мы живём в век нанотехнологий.
10. With "**это время**", the pattern is **в + винительный падеж.**

    > В это время дверь открылась и вошёл директор.
11. With "**скорое время**", the pattern is **в + предложный падеж.**

    > В скором времени начнётся строительство нового дома.
12. With exact **dates**, we use **родительный падеж**. Mind that this pattern is used only when we answer the question "When?"/"Когда?"

    > Премьера фильма состоялась 20-го июля 2002-ого года.

Comment: "В году" - here is the second prepositional, the fist is "о годе"

Comment: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/419678/В-2015-году-какой-падеж

Comment: "В + местный падеж" - locative case is not recognized in Russian. Formally, in this case, it would be дательный падеж.

Comment: @Alexander no, it is not Dative. Those who do not recognize Locative consider it Locative form of Prepositional case.

Comment: @Anixx "Those who do not recognize Locative consider it Locative form of Prepositional case." - citation needed.

Comment: @Alexander https://starling.rinet.ru/cgi-bin/morph.cgi?flags=wndnnnnp&root=config&word=%E3%EE%E4%F3

Comment: @Alexander It can't be dative anyway. In dative the stress is on the first syllable, in the locative form it's on the second.

Answer (score 8):

In languages that have prepositions and cases, like Russian, each preposition in each of its meanings needs a particular case of the noun phrase that follows it.

As for the preposition **в** when used to denote specific time, the cases of the nouns after **в** are as follows,

**Accusative case:**

- exact time: *в **пять** часов **одну** **минуту*** (at 5:01);
- the days of the week: *в **понедельник**, в **среду**, в **пятницу**, в **субботу**, в **воскресенье***.

**Prepositional case:**

- months: *в **январе**, в **марте**, в **августе***;
- years: *в **две тысячи двадцатом году***;
- centuries, millennia, geological epochs: *в **двадцать первом веке***, *в **третьем тысячелетии***, *в **кайнозойской эре*** (here, the accusative is also possible: *в **кайнозойскую эру***).

The case used after a preposition depends **only** on the preposition and its meaning in the given utterance; there's no connection with the overall sentence structure or the presence or absence of objects.